# Couchdb authentication works but doesn't store cookie

Tags: ajax, cookies, couchdb

I'm trying to authentify to my couchdb instance using ajax and cookie authentication.

I send the following POST request to couchdb:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:5984/_session",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    username: "myUsername",
    password: "myPassword",
  },
  success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  },
});
```

The response I receive:

```
{ name: "myUsername", ok: true, roles: [ "someRoles" ] }
```

So far everything looks perfect.
But if I then make the following GET request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:5984/_session",
  type: "GET",
  success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  },
});
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{
  info: { authentication_db: "_users", authentication_handlers: […] },
  ok: true,
  userCtx: { name: null, roles: [] }
}
```

Also I noticed that my browser doesn't seem to save any cookie when authenticating.
What am I not getting? Is there anything more step I should do for the cookie authentication to work?